# Table data rows when scrolled are visible behind sticky table header

Tags: html, css, reactjs

In my project im creating a table that contains a sticky header and below there are scrollable data.

Every time i scroll the data the row is visible behind the sticky header.

[image]

My HTML code:

```html
               <div className='main-body'>
                        <div className='table-container'>
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>VM Name</th>
                                        <th>OS</th>
                                        <th>VM Status</th>
                                        <th>Expiration Date</th>
                                        <th>Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            {virtualMachines.map((vm) => (
                                <tr key={vm.id}>
                                    <td>{vm.id}</td>
                                    <td>{vm.vmName}</td>
                                    <td>{vm.os}</td>
                                    <td>{vm.status}</td>
                                    <td>{vm.expirationDate}</td>
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My CSS code:

```css
.main-body {
    background: lightskyblue;
    height: 80vh;
    position: relative;

    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.table-container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 25px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    min-height: 0%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

thead {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

thead th {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

tbody td {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
```

I tried to create the header and the body of the table in different containers but made the two parts not aligning properly.

Any ideas how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div className='main-body'>
    <div className='table-container'>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <!-- Header content -->
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <!-- Body content -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-body {
    background: lightskyblue;
    height: 80vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.table-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

thead th,
tbody td {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

thead th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}

tbody td {
    background-color: white; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but the table body is not aligned with the header even if i give the same padding.

Comment: You right. I check again and edit my answer now its work well

Comment: It still shows the row behind the header.

Comment: ِdid you exactly that???

Comment: Sorry my mistake i forgot to comment out my previous table container inside my css.